# Missing required parameter for Route

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I am working with Laravel 5.3. I have a controller function that has $id has its argument

```
public function verifyMe ($id){
        $user = User::findOrfail($id);
        return view ('dashboard');
    }
```

I have in my route, a url with this $id parameter.

```
Route::get('/verify/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@verifyMe',
    'as' => 'VerifyMe',
]);
```

Also in my blade template, I have this

```
<h3>To verify, <a href="{{route('verifyMe', ['id' => $user->id])}}">Click Here.</a> </h3>
```

But I get this error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: verifyMe] [URI: verify/{id}].

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: do you have any subdomain ?

Comment: Also share how `$user` assigned and passed here ?

Comment: I assigned my user with $user = new User;

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `$user->id` ? can you share all code ?

Comment: Is the user found?

Comment: yes I dd($user) and got the required parameters, More so, i have the user registered in my database already.

Comment: @olasunkanmi : just check with `$user->id ?? 1` default value as 1 to check ?

Answer (score 0):

In your template, remove `$user->id` and put `auth()->user()->id` and see whether it'll work.

The issue i think, is variable `$user`.

Comment: i am not using the laravel built in auth system, I created my sign up and Sign in logic.

Comment: Try it first. Either way it's gonna pick an id, unless if you removed the whole Auth.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and tried a way like this

Try this

```
<h3>To verify, <a href="{{route(['verifyMe', 'id' => $user->id])}}">Click 
Here.</a> </h3>
```

I hope it helps